# Why does the setState not trigger a re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I'am trying to trigger a re-render to exclude my header and footer.

When I log the page, it first triggers render > componentDidMount > render, so I would assume the page did update with the correct values, but it still shows the header/footer.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      header: true,
      footer: true,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (window.location.pathname === '/404-page') {
      this.setState({ header: false, footer: false });
    } else if (window.location.pathname === '/form') {
      this.setState({ header: true, footer: false });
    } else if (window.location.pathname.length > 6) {
      this.setState({ header: true, footer: false });
    }
  }
 render() {
    {header ? <Header /> : null}
 }
```

The result would be that the header/footer aren't there anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to destructure the property `header` from `state`. Then explictly `return`

```
 render() {
    const {header} = this.state
    return header ? <Header /> : null
 }
```

Comment: wow, cant believe I missed that.. but it still doesnt fix it
edit: forgot the return :) cheers! Its fixed!

Comment: did you check the header value?